# What's the purpose of this lambda?

Tags: c++, c++14

I see the following lambda in C++ code. What's the purpose of it?

```cpp
static const auto faster = [](){
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    return nullptr;
}();
```

Comment: Call those functions before `main`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think having this at namespace scope is fraught with peril. You could not guarantee whether it runs before or after any code that is part of initialization of non-local static variables in any other translation unit. And presumably this is what you care about - otherwise you would just put this at the beginning of `main`.

Comment: @Brian: Unless of course, you're writing a library that has no control over `main`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If you're writing a library that has no control over `main`, then you have no business messing with the standard C++ streams in this way.

Comment: @ruakh let's not point at Qt and others..

Answer (score 22):

A local `static` variable is initialized at most once, by the first thread that executes its declaration. By using a lambda, we can take advantage of this fact to run arbitrary code at most once. The first time the declaration is reached, the thread that reaches it will execute the code in the lambda as part of initializing the variable. The variable's value is presumably not actually used, but the program will remember that the variable has been initialized, so the lambda will not be run a second time.

Comment: But the lambda isn't really what allows us to run arbitrary code right? We could use a normal function too? It seems to me the lambda is mainly there to make it a simple, single declaration?

Comment: @BasinhetVeld Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 9):

You typically see this code in competitive programming contest submissions for online judges that use C++ I/O behind the scenes. In order to boost the clock runtime of your submissions, you can untie the streams and unsychronize C++ IOStreams from the standard C streams. The use of the lambda is a slick way to execute the code immediately where the variable is declared. In order to get the full effect of this optimization it should be placed before any other code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is called an Immediatly Invoked Lambda (IIL).

First the lambda (`[] () {...}`) is been declared, then immediatly it is called (invoked) (`()` - immediatly after the lambda).

This can be used in a number of ways:

- initialize a const variable by complicated logic

```
    const auto v = [] () {
        if (...) return X;
        else return Y;
   }
```

- initialize a static variable with complicated logic
- call a IIL to create a value for a parameter of a function

```
     auto x = foo(a, b, [c] () {return c > 42;} () );
```

- because static variables are initialized early on, by using a static variable whose value will be ignored, but is initialized with an IIL - it can be used to perform actions before execution of `main`.

Comment: 3. To execute an action early, before entering `main`.